# Is there a dedicated book for headers and footers?

Tags: footer, header

I need to improve on my first attempt at LaTeX—please advise—is there a dedicated book for headers and footers?

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

%font for typing
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{garamond}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{cmtt}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\usepackage{avant}
%\usepackage{bookman}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{utopia}
%\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{tgtermes}
%usepackagecourier{Courier(Typewriter)}
                                                    %preamble
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}                 %maths
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                             %no hyphenation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{indentfirst}

%header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Place Title Here}}       %italics sl=slant caps
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Student Name}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}










\begin{document}

%title page
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\line(1,0){500}\\
[.25in]
\huge \textsc{ Quality Management System Manual}\\
[2mm]
\line(1,0){500}\\
[2mm]
\textsc{\Large as per requirements of std iso 9001:2015}
                                        \begin{figure}[H]
                                        \centering
                                        \includegraphics[scale=2]{../../images/"dgqa logo".png} 
                                        %\caption{DGQA Logo}
                                        \label{DGQA Logo}
                                        \end{figure}

\vfill
\line(1,0){500}\\

\textsc{\normalsize CONTROLLERATE OF QUALITY ASSURANCE\\ARMOURED VEHICLE ELECTRONICS\\GOVERNMENT OF INDIA\\ MIN OF DEFENCE (DGQA)\\AVADI, CHENNAI -- 600 054\\tel: 044-26843007, fax: 044-26841881, email:} {\normalsize  cqaavl-dgqa@nic.in}\\ 

\line(1,0){500}\\
\scriptsize NOT TO BE COPIED OR REPRODUCED IN FULL OR PART WITHOUT PERMISSION OF CONTROLLER, CQA(AVL
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}












%toc
%acknowledgement
%figures
%tables
%annexures
%main content

\section{Scope}\label{sec:Scope}


\section{Normative Reference}\label{sec:Normative Reference}
\begin{quote}
                ISO 9001-2015   - Quality management system requirements\\
                ISO 19011:2015  - Guidelines for auditing management systems\\
                DGQA standing orders\\
                CQA(AVL) standing orders
\end{quote}


\section{Terms and Definitions}\label{sec:Terms and Definitions}


\section{Context of the Organization}\label{sec:Context of the Organiszation}
\subsection{Understanding the organization and its context}
e Min es for electrical/electronic gun control equipment and associated cable assembly manufactured at HVF and OFMK and fitted in tanks and also render complete resident Quality Assurance support for the items manufactured at HVF


\begin{quote}
General Information about the establishment 
        \begin{quote}
        Location of CQA(AVL): Inside HVF campus at Avadi\\
        Total manpower              : 50

        Distance from Railway station   
                \begin{quote}
                Avadi               : 5km\\
                Chennai Central     : 28km\\
                Airport, Meenambakkam   : 38km
                \end{quote}

    \end{quote}

\end{quote}


In the scotesting facilities for running trial and the Proof Range Complex for firing if the tanks located outside the main factory Area are also not covered.


\subsection{Control of externally provided processes, products and services}

\subsubsection{General}


CQA(AVL) for the quirement and retain documented information of these activities and any necessary actions arising from the evaluation 
\subsubsection{Type and extent of control}
\begin{itemize}
\item   CQA(AVL) does not have any externally provided products or services
\item   Stores section of CQA(AVL) does the verification of product supplied by vendors before accepting the item 
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Information for external providers}
\begin{itemize}
\item   Information about the product is collected by stores through requisition/indent received through wings/sections, the same information is communicated to the vendor and is verified by the purchase committee
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Production and service provision}

\subsubsection{Control of Production and service provision}

CQA(AVL) implements production and service provision under controlled conditions as follows
\begin{itemize}
\item   Availability of documented information (drawing, specifications, process sheets, acceptance test procedures) that define the characteristics of Quality Assurance activities and the results to be achieved
\item   Availability of suitable monitoring and measuring resources (test stand, test beds, test facilities of HVF /vendors/DPSUs)
\item   Monitoring and measurement activities are implemented at appropriate stage (JEs-AEs-AC-DC-JC-Controller) to verify that criteria for control of processes and acceptance criteria for products and services are met
\item   Actions to prevent human error are taken through cross-verification and automation of processes
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Identification and traceability}

CQA(AVL) has ensured that where traceability is a requirement, the establishment controls and records 
Identification of the following are maintained throughout the process 
\begin{itemize}
\item   I-Note/QAC          -   Quality Assurance section
\item   Quality audit report        -   QMS section
\item   Vetted indents          -   AHSP section
\item Vetted scales         -   AHSP section
\item   Codified items          -   AHSP section
\item   Digitized drawings /documents       -   AHSP section

\item   Defect report with corrective/preventive action     -   AHSP section

\item   Trained manpower        -   P \& C section
\item Purchased products        -   Stores section
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Property belonging to customers or external providers}

CQA(AVL) does not use any property belonging to customers or external providers
    \subsubsection{Preservation}

ts with respect to Quality Assurance of equipment and the same are preserved
\subsubsection{Post-delivery activities}

Defect investigation is the main post-delivery activity of CQA(AVL), during defect investigation the establishment considers the following
\begin{itemize}
\item   Statutory and regulatory requirement (warranty clause)
\item   Customer requirement and feedback
\end{itemize}
    \subsubsection{Control of changes}

Changes in documented information with respect to product or service are done after review
\begin{itemize}
\item   Changes to Quality Assurance plan is done with the approval of Controller after discussion with JCs
\item   Documented information is maintained for changes
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Release of products and services}
\begin{itemize}
\item   I-Notes and QAC are issued after checks at various stages by Quality Assurance section -- noting sheets are kept as evidence
\item   In AHSP, P \& C, stores section the vetted indents, codification, digitization, defect investigation, training and store procurement are verified at appropriate stages and checked for satisfactory completion
\item   Documented information is retained on the release and traceability to the staff authorizing the release 
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Control of nonconforming outputs}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Non-conforming products are identified at every stage, segregated and sent for rectification and corrected
    \item Documented information is retained describing the non-conformity, action taken, identification of the authority deciding the action in respect of the non-conformity
    \item On the AHSP side, re-vetting of indents, re-codification and re-digitization is carried out if the output of services are non-conforming
\end{itemize}
\cleardoublepage
\section{Performance evaluation}
\subsection{Monitoring, measurement, analysis and evaluation}
\subsubsection{General}
CQA(AVL) has determined what needs to be monitored, measured and evaluated as below

\begin{center}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3cm} %for each column
\begin{tabular}{p{1.3in} p{1.5in}  p{1.3in}   p{1.8in}} \hline
\textbf{What is to be monitored and measured}  & \textbf{Methods for monitoring, measurement and evaluation} & \textbf{When to monitor and measure} & \textbf{When the inputs from monitoring and measurement to be analysed and evaluated}\\ \hline
Effectiveness of QA activity    &   Analysing the defects received on equipment for a given period  & Half yearly & Half yearly\\ \cline{2-4} %horizontal line spanning clolumn 2 to 4
    {} &    Feedback received from customer JRI &   Half yearly & Half yearly\\ \hline
    Effectiveness of AHSP activities &  Customer feedback   & Half yearly   & Half yearly\\ \hline
Effectiveness of quality management system  &   Internal audit  & Once every four months &  Once every four months\\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

CQA(AVL) retains documented evidence of the results above
\subsubsection{Customer satisfaction}
CQA(AVL) monitors customer perception of the degree to which their needs and expectations have been fulfilled through
\begin{itemize}
\item Customer feedback on product/service rendered
\item Meetings with the customers
\item Compliments from customers
\end{itemize}


\subsubsection{Analysis and evaluation}
CQA(AVL)  opportunities and the need for improvement of quality management system 
\subsection{Internal audit}
CQA(AVL) plans and conductncluding customer and contractual requirement as deemed necessary and applicable. Authorised representative along with internal audit team to ensure that the audit scope, frequency and methods are defined and the following requirement are satisfactorily achieved

\begin{itemize}
\item Implementation of previous audit results
\item Communication of audit result to the management 

\end{itemize}

CQA(AVL) has defined the procedure for internal audit as below

\begin{itemize}
\item Audit schedule will be prepared by the QMS Coord and approved by the management representative
\item Audit schedule will cover aspects of quality management system
\item Audits are scings
\item Management reprement representative and QMS Coord
\end{itemize}

CQA(AVL) plans the audit as below

\begin{itemize}
\item Circular issued by the QMS Coord after the approval of management representative notifying the dates, at least three days in advance of the audit. The auditor will have no responsibility in the Area or function being audited
\item Auditors will be given a set of forms as below
\begin{itemize}
\item Internal audit plan
\item Internal audit check list
\item Internal audit program/schedule
\item Internal audit report
\item Non-conformance form
\end{itemize}
\item Respective Joint Controller will ensure that all documents such as quality manual, operating procedures, work instructions, specifications and previous audit results are available for review and planning the audit 
\item Audit check list will be prepared by the auditor based on the documents and processes to be audited
\end{itemize}

CQA(AVL) performs the internal audit as below
\begin{itemize}
\item Auditors will conduct the audit as per the following
\begin{itemize}
\item Using the prepared internal audit check list examining the objective evidence provided and record on the check list all observations with appropriate reason in the remarks column, or,
\item Using a blank audit check list going through clause by clause of the document being audited and noting all non-conformance on an audit check list against relevant clause number
\end{itemize}
\item All non-conformances (NCs) will be reported in non-conformance(s) report
\item The auditor will return the forms to management representative, who will explain the findings of the audit during closing meeting
\item Management representative will place the audit report with summary of audit findings in management review meeting
\item Non-conformance(s) report will be closed by management representative based on the evidence submitted by the auditee with regard to corrective action taken 
\end{itemize}

CQA(AVL) plans the follow up action as under
\begin{itemize}
\item The auditee will undertake corrective action within the agreed date and produce evidence to the team leader internal audit
\item The auditor will review or carry out follow up visit to verify implementation of the corrective action
\item If satisfactory, the non-conformance(s) report will be closed
\end{itemize}


\subsection{Management review}



\subsubsection{General}
CQA(AVL) management review process is planned and includes the following 
\begin{itemize}
\item The establisment
\item QMS Coord tes will be circulated and the absent member may endorse the minutes later
\item Controller will chair the management review meeting 
\item Minutes of the meeting will be recorded on an approved format
\item Audit representative will circulate the minutes of the management review meeting after approval of the chairperson of the management review meeting within ten days of the mtg
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Management review inputs}
Assessment of the quality management system is based on a review of information inputs to management review. Input considerations include
\begin{itemize}
    \item The status of actions from previous management reviews
\item Change in internal and external issues that are relevant to the quality management system
\item Information on the performance and effectiveness of the quality management system, including trends
\begin{itemize}
    \item Customer satisfaction and feedback format relevant to the interested parties
\item The extent to which the quality objectives have been met 
\item Process performance and conformity of products and services
\item Non-conformance(s) and corrective action
\item Monitoring and measurement results
\item Audit results
\end{itemize}

\item Adequacy of resources
\item The effectiveness of actions taken to address risks and opportunities -- clause 6.1
\item Opportunities for improvement 
\end{itemize}


\subsubsection{Management review outputs}
Management review outputs include decisions and actions related to the following
\begin{itemize}
    \item Opportunities for improvement
\item Changes needed to the quality management system
\item Resource required

\end{itemize}
Documents of the management review meeting are retained as evidence of the results of management review
\cleardoublepage
\section{Improvement}

\subsection{General}    
CQA(AVL) determines and selects opportunities for improvement and implements necessary actions to meet enhance customer satisfaction, these include
\begin{itemize}
\item Improving Quality Assurance and AHSP activities to meet requirement as well as to address future needs and expectations
\item Correcting, preventing or reducing undesired effects, which affect Quality Assurance, AHSP activities and quality management system
\item Improving the performance and effectiveness of the quality management system
\end{itemize}


\subsection{Nonconformity and corrective action}
\begin{itemize}
\item CQA(AVL) initiates actions to eliminate the cause of non-conformance(s) in order to prevent recurrence. 
\item Corrective actions are appropriate to the effects of non-conformance(s) encountered. 
\item When non-conformance(s) occurs, corrective action procedures are initiated and implemented, examples of such actions include

\begin{itemize}
\item Taking action to control and correct it
\item Reviewing and analyzing the non-conformance(s) – brainstorming 
\item Determining the cause of the non-conformance(s)
\item Determining if similar non-conformance(s) exist, or could potentially occur
\item Implementation of any action needed
\item Review of the effectiveness of any corrective action taken
\item Updating risks and opportunities determined during planning, if necessary
\item Making changes to the quality management system, if necessary
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
CQA(AVL) will retain documented information as evidence of
\begin{itemize}
\item The nature of the non-conformance(s) and subsequent action
\item The results of any corrective action
\item Quality management system non-conformance(s) will be identified through
\begin{itemize}
\item Internal audit
\item Customer complaint
\item Data analysis
\item Management review meeting 
\end{itemize}

\item Management will fix responsibility and target date through an management review meeting; evaluation of the non-conformance(s) will be carried out through quality control tools to determine the potential cause and root cause; this will be followed by corrective action 
\end{itemize}


\subsection{Continual improvement}
 CQA(AVL) will consider the following inputs for Continual improvement of quality management system
\begin{itemize}
\item Quality policy
\item Quality objective
\item Internal audits
\item Non-conformance(s)
\item Corrective action
\item Customer feedback
\item Customer complaint
\item Minutes of management review meeting 
\item Results of statistical quality control study
\item Risk and SWOT analysis
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain better your issue? What is the problem you have with your headers and footers?  Had you read the documentation of `fancyhdr` with `texdoc fanvyhdr` in your terminal/console?

Comment: Off topic:  `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so it's not necessary to load both.  In addition, it is *really* not necessary (or desirable) to load either `amsmath` or `amssymb` twice.  In these cases, no harm is done, but that's not always true.